# Printing using globals() in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the shape for each dataset but it doesn't print as I would like.

```
for i in train_set, train_labels, test_set, test_labels:
    name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is i][1]
    print("The {0} shape is {1}".format(name, i.shape))
```

The output is:

The i shape is (1700, 20)

The i shape is (1700,)

The i shape is (300, 20)

The i shape is (300,)

The value of 'i' is not being replaced. Can someone guide me what's wrong in this:

Comment: Add another condition to ignore any globals named `i`?: `[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is i and x != 'i']`

Comment: The first time through the loop, both `i` and `train_set` will pass the `thing is i` test.  You seem to be assuming that those will be delivered in alphabetical order.  If you're running Python 2.7, that isn't true.  Overall, this code is just very bad practice.  If you need to refer to these by name, then store them in a dictionary: `names['train_set']`, `names['train_labels']`, etc.  Then this becomes easy.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Is there a better way of writing the above ? I just thought of not repeating many print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just for debugging or status info, here's the right way:

```
for name,table in (
    ('train_set', train_set),
    ('train_labels', train_labels),
    ('test_set', test_set),
    ('test_labels', test_labels) ):
    print("The {0} shape is {1}".format(name, table.shape)
```

If you need to have the names for more than just this, then don't create them in individual variables:

```
data['train_set'] = train_set
data['train_labels'] = train_labels
data['test_set'] = test_set
data['test_labels'] = test_labels
```

Now you have the names and the tables in one convenient location.